# Dell D630 - Touchpad does not move the mouse cursor

Tags: windows-xp, dell-latitude, synaptics-touchpad

Windows XP - Dell D630 - Synaptics Touch Pad driver installed.

The system tray icon that shows the movement of your finger on the touchpad registeres movement.  The scroll feature of the touchpad works on any window with a scroll bar. The double click works even. But it never actually moves the cursor on the screen.  An external mouse works with out problems, and I've replaced the palm-rest/touchpad and it continues to happen. The touch stick in the middle of the keyboard works without problems.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where did you get the touch pad driver? What version?

Answer (score 1):

Some touchpads have a disable button, it either sounds like yours is partially active (cursor doesn't move) or partially inactive (scrolling works) so that would be the first thing I would look for...